# Handle specific exception from a python package, which is not directly imported

Tags: python, error-handling, package, packaging

I have developed a python package **Child**, which is used by another python package **Main**.  Python Package **Child** uses and imports the default mysql connector.

```
import mysql.connector as sql  # pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Within the **Main** package I run a function imported from the Package **Child**, which uses the mysql connector. When running this function from the **Main** package I want to handle a specifc mysql exception, without installing the mysql connector by default in the **Main** package as it will be installed within the **Child** package anyway.

I'm using poetry for dependency managment.

What's the best approach?

Comment: Title says "raise", question body says "handle". Which one is it? Either way, just import the exception type and use it. As long as `mysql` is available it does not matter what installed it.

Comment: Thank you. Changed that title, it was indeed confusing. You are right, I can just import the package. I think I just thought to long about it and to late in the evening ^^

Comment: Note, if you are going to import it, then you should add it as an explicit dependency of the main package

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that is what I wanted to avoid, because it seems kind of overkill just importing the package for importing his exceptions. Are there any disadvantages, when I don't import it?